# Whats the difference between OnApplicationFocus() and OnApplicationPause()?

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, background

Speaking of mobile devices, whats the difference between those two methods? If I press the home key both are called. Is there any situation when one is called and not the other?

Answer (score 9):

> Since this UnityAnswer is one of the first (if not the first) to be
>   returned on a search for OnApplicationFocus/Pause & iOS, an important
>   update in Unity 4.6.1 has changed the behavior for iOS.
>
> As of 4.6.1, both OnApplicationFocus and OnApplicationPause will be
>   called in iOS.
>
> The order is :
>
> App initially starts:
>
> OnApplicationFocus(true) is called
>
> App is soft closed:
>
> OnApplicationFocus(false) is called
>
> OnApplicationPause(true) is called
>
> App is brought forward after soft closing:
>
> OnApplicationPause(false) is called
>
> OnApplicationFocus(true) is called
>
> Hope that helps

http://answers.unity.com/answers/970958/view.html